# Preserve names when coercing vector from binary to `as.numeric`?

Tags: r, vector, type-conversion, names

In R, when you coerce a vector from binary to numeric, the names are stripped away.

There are a few possible solutions, which I've outlined before. It seems dangerous to rely on implicit conversion by adding 0 to all the values, and the `sapply()` adds an additional loop to my operations (which seems inefficient). Is there any other way to preserve the names when converting a vector using `as.numeric`?

```
# Set the seed
set.seed(1045)

# Create a small sample vector and give it names
example_vec <- sample(x = c(TRUE,FALSE),size = 10,replace = TRUE)
names(example_vec) <- sample(x = LETTERS,size = 10,replace = FALSE)

example_vec
#     Y     N     M     P     L     J     H     O     F     D 
# FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE 

as.numeric(x = example_vec)
#  [1] 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1

example_vec + 0
# Y N M P L J H O F D 
# 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 

sapply(X = example_vec,FUN = as.numeric)
# Y N M P L J H O F D 
# 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: Changing the `class()` to numeric seems to have the same effect as changing the storage mode.

Comment: Rather ugly, but you could run `setNames(as.numeric(example_vec), names(example_vec))`

Comment: I don't see any risk in implicit or explicit conversion. If you like integers and typing fewer characters, use `+example_vec`. Also, I don't see any reason to tag with data.table unless you're thinking of using `setattr` or something.

Comment: Ah, ok. I don't think it's difficult. I don't have 3.3.0, but `+example_vec` works fine for me.

Comment: I agree with @Frank. Reapplying the names via `setNames` somehow _feels_ the most reliable, but I feel like the risks of `example_vec + 0L` or `+example_vec` are quite low.

Comment: @Frank I think you're right, actually. This is more of a base R question, not a `data.table` Q.

Comment: The issue with `+example_vec` is that it is confusing.  If you haven't seen the trick, you're going to be confused reading the code as to what is happening.  To be clear, you'd need to write a comment, and that point you have the same amount of typing as `setNames(as.numeric(example_vec), names(example_vec))` anyway.

Comment: @MatthewDrury The confusion with the `+` essentially carries over to `as.integer` -- you have to know that TRUE/FALSE becomes 1L/0L when coerced. And, I mean, if you're the type of person inclined to clarify code by commenting there, why not go a step further and keep the code clear by actually using a Boolean type for a Boolean variable instead of moving to 1/0? (Note that there is no reason to ever use `numeric` for a Boolean or categorical column...I don't know why people are always using it on SO.)

Comment: @Frank Completely agree with all that, though I would have no idea what was even being attempted if I saw a `+example_vec` in some code, while `as.numeric` would at least communicate some intent.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just to throw another option out there, since your input is a logical vector, you can use `ifelse()`. And one could argue this approach is more explicit and straightforward:

```
ifelse(example_vec,1L,0L);
## Y N M P L J H O F D
## 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

---

## Benchmarking

```
library(microbenchmark);

ifelse. <- function(x) ifelse(x,1L,0L);
sapply. <- function(x) sapply(x,as.integer);
setstoragemode <- function(x) { storage.mode(x) <- 'integer'; x; };
setmode <- function(x) { mode(x) <- 'integer'; x; };
setclass <- function(x) { class(x) <- 'integer'; x; };
as.and.setnames <- function(x) setNames(as.integer(x),names(x));
plus <- function(x) +x;
addzero <- function(x) x+0L;
```

---

```
## small scale (OP's example input)
set.seed(1045L);
x <- sample(c(T,F),10L,T);
names(x) <- sample(LETTERS,10L);

ex <- ifelse.(x);
identical(ex,sapply.(x));
## [1] TRUE
identical(ex,setstoragemode(x));
## [1] TRUE
identical(ex,setmode(x));
## [1] TRUE
identical(ex,setclass(x));
## [1] TRUE
identical(ex,as.and.setnames(x));
## [1] TRUE
identical(ex,plus(x));
## [1] TRUE
identical(ex,addzero(x));
## [1] TRUE

microbenchmark(ifelse.(x),sapply.(x),setstoragemode(x),setmode(x),setclass(x),as.and.setnames(x),plus(x),addzero(x));
## Unit: nanoseconds
##                expr   min      lq     mean median      uq   max neval
##          ifelse.(x)  6843  8126.0  9627.13   8981  9837.0 21810   100
##          sapply.(x) 18817 20100.5 23234.93  21383 22666.5 71418   100
##   setstoragemode(x)   856  1283.0  1745.54   1284  1711.0 15396   100
##          setmode(x)  7270  8126.0  9862.36   8982 10264.0 32074   100
##         setclass(x)   429  1283.0  2138.97   1284  1712.0 32075   100
##  as.and.setnames(x)  1283  1711.0  1997.78   1712  2139.0  7271   100
##             plus(x)     0   428.0   492.39    428   428.5  9837   100
##          addzero(x)     0   428.0   539.39    428   856.0  2566   100
```

---

```
## large scale
set.seed(1L);
N <- 1e5L;
x <- sample(c(T,F),N,T);
names(x) <- make.unique(rep_len(LETTERS,N));

ex <- ifelse.(x);
identical(ex,sapply.(x));
## [1] TRUE
identical(ex,setstoragemode(x));
## [1] TRUE
identical(ex,setmode(x));
## [1] TRUE
identical(ex,setclass(x));
## [1] TRUE
identical(ex,as.and.setnames(x));
## [1] TRUE
identical(ex,plus(x));
## [1] TRUE
identical(ex,addzero(x));
## [1] TRUE

microbenchmark(ifelse.(x),sapply.(x),setstoragemode(x),setmode(x),setclass(x),as.and.setnames(x),plus(x),addzero(x));
## Unit: microseconds
##                expr       min          lq         mean      median         uq        max neval
##          ifelse.(x)  7633.598   7757.1900  16615.71251   7897.4600  29401.112  96503.642   100
##          sapply.(x) 86353.737 102576.0945 125547.32957 123909.1120 137900.406 264442.788   100
##   setstoragemode(x)    84.676     92.8015    343.46124     98.3605    113.543  23939.133   100
##          setmode(x)   124.020    155.0245    603.15744    167.2125    181.111  22395.736   100
##         setclass(x)    85.104     92.3740    328.25393    100.2850    118.460  21807.713   100
##  as.and.setnames(x)    70.991     78.2610    656.98177     82.3235     88.953  35710.697   100
##             plus(x)    40.200     42.9795     48.68026     44.9040     49.608     88.953   100
##          addzero(x)   181.326    186.4580    196.34882    189.6650    201.211    282.679   100
```

---

```
## very large scale
set.seed(1L);
N <- 1e7L;
x <- sample(c(T,F),N,T);
names(x) <- make.unique(rep_len(LETTERS,N));

ex <- ifelse.(x);
identical(ex,sapply.(x));
## [1] TRUE
identical(ex,setstoragemode(x));
## [1] TRUE
identical(ex,setmode(x));
## [1] TRUE
identical(ex,setclass(x));
## [1] TRUE
identical(ex,as.and.setnames(x));
## [1] TRUE
identical(ex,plus(x));
## [1] TRUE
identical(ex,addzero(x));
## [1] TRUE

microbenchmark(ifelse.(x),sapply.(x),setstoragemode(x),setmode(x),setclass(x),as.and.setnames(x),plus(x),addzero(x),times=5L);
## Unit: milliseconds
##                expr          min           lq         mean       median           uq         max neval
##          ifelse.(x)  1082.220903  1308.106967  3452.639836  1473.723533  6306.320235  7092.82754     5
##          sapply.(x) 16766.199371 17431.458634 18401.672635 18398.345499 18843.890150 20568.46952     5
##   setstoragemode(x)    13.298283    13.648103   173.574496    19.661753    24.736278   796.52806     5
##          setmode(x)    19.043796    19.878573    75.669779    19.969235    39.683589   279.77370     5
##         setclass(x)    14.025292    14.119804   259.627934    14.414457    26.838618  1228.74150     5
##  as.and.setnames(x)    12.889875    24.241484   178.243948    24.962934    25.103631   804.02182     5
##             plus(x)     7.577576     7.676364     9.047674     8.245142     8.253266    13.48602     5
##          addzero(x)    18.861615    18.960403    71.284716    26.622226    26.950662   265.02867     5
```

---

Looks like the unary plus takes the cake. (And my `ifelse()` idea kinda sucks.)

Comment: I'm curious why some of the means are much greater than the medians. For example in the final example ("very large scale"), `setstoragemode` and `setmode` have essentially the same medians (20 milliseconds) but the means are 174 ms and 76 ms respectively. For `setclass` there's an even greater disparity; the mean is 260 ms while the mean is only 14 ms.

Answer (score 16):

One possibility is to use the `mode<-` replacement function to change the internal storage mode (type) of the object.   Also, integers are more appropriate than doubles (i.e. numerics) for this case of logical coercion.

```
mode(example_vec) <- "integer"
example_vec
# Y N M P L J H O F D 
# 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

From `help(mode)` -

> `mode(x) <- "newmode"` changes the mode of object `x` to `newmode`. This is only supported if there is an appropriate `as.newmode` function, for example `"logical"`, `"integer"`, `"double"`, `"complex"`, `"raw"`, `"character"`, `"list"`, `"expression"`, `"name"`, `"symbol"` and `"function"`. **Attributes are preserved**.

The documentation also notes that `storage.mode<-` is a more efficient primitive version of `mode<-`.  So the following could also be used.

```
storage.mode(example_vec) <- "integer"
```

But as @joran pointed out in the comments, it looks like `class<-` also does the same thing.