# R: how to extend condition by group

Tags: r, dataframe

I have an unbalanced panel (with 7 million observations for some 800k individuals). I want to create a new variable that is equal to `1`, if that person has ever responded `yes` to another question. Specifically, I want to create a dummy that is equal to one if the individual has EVER smoked.

So let's say my dataset looks something like this (where `ID` is unique to each individual, and some people are interviewed many times, and other people only once):

```
ID   Smoke 
 1      No  
 1      No
 1     Yes
 1      No
 2      No
 2      No
 3     Yes
 3      No
```

And I want to generate a variable `Ever_Smoked`, to look something like:

```
ID   Smoke  Ever_Smoked
 1      No            1
 1      No            1
 1     Yes            1
 1      No            1
 2      No            0
 2      No            0
 3     Yes            1
 3      No            1
```

Any ideas on how to do this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Angustin Indaco You can format tables the way you tried using 4 whitespaces as indentation (which makes them source code).

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to figure out how to do this. Long time avid reader of StackOverflow, first time I post something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a base R solution using `ave()`:

```
df$Ever_Smoked <- ave(+(df$Smoke=='Yes'),df$ID,FUN=max);
df;
##   ID Smoke Ever_Smoked
## 1  1    No           1
## 2  1    No           1
## 3  1   Yes           1
## 4  1    No           1
## 5  2    No           0
## 6  2    No           0
## 7  3   Yes           1
## 8  3    No           1
```

**Data**

```
df <- data.frame(ID=c(1L,1L,1L,1L,2L,2L,3L,3L),Smoke=c('No','No','Yes','No','No','No','Yes',
'No'),stringsAsFactors=F);
```

---

Coincidentally, [today I did some benchmarking on different ways of converting a logical vector to an integer vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37951199/in-r-how-can-i-preserve-the-names-of-a-vector-when-using-as-numeric/37951526#37951526), and found that the unary plus is the speediest. That's why I chose it for my answer here.

Of course, the call to `ave()` will incur a significant performance hit, at least relative to data.table's indexing implementation. Thus, for best performance, I'd suggest you use rafa's data.table implementation, but use the unary plus solution for converting logical to integer.

Comment: Yes, this was very fast. And seems to work fine as far I can see. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Given the size of your dataset, a solution based on `data.table` is probably the best/fastest alternative

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[, Ever_Smoked := as.numeric(any(Smoke=="Yes")), by = ID]
```

**Performance test** using the sample data provided by @bgoldst:

```
df <- data.frame(ID=c(1L,1L,1L,1L,2L,2L,3L,3L),Smoke=c('No','No','Yes','No','No','No','Yes','No'),stringsAsFactors=F)

# make it a 8 million row dataset 
df <- df[rep(seq_len(nrow(df)), 1000000), ] 

system.time( setDT(df)[, Ever_Smoked := as.numeric(any(Smoke=="Yes")), by = ID] )

#>  user  system elapsed 
#>  0.27    0.01    0.32
```

Comment: I agree on this - guess I should suggest more `data.table` solutions altogether ;)

Comment: This doesn't give the correct result though, as not all `Ever_Smoked` cases end up being one for the group. You need something like `setDT(df)[, Ever_Smoked := as.numeric(any(Smoke=="Yes")), by = ID]` instead.

Comment: Well spotted @thelatemail, thank you for the heads up !

Answer (score 1):

You can split your data along `ID` and assign the appropriate value to each subset individually:

```
d <- data.frame(ID = c(rep(1,4), rep(2,2), rep(3,2)), Smoke=c('No', 'No', 'Yes', rep('No', 3), 'Yes', 'No'))

library(plyr)
d2 <- ldply(split(d, d$ID), function(d_tmp) {
    d_tmp$Ever_Smoked <- ifelse(all(d_tmp$Smoke=='No'), 0, 1)
    d_tmp
})[,-1]
```

...which should be what you intend to obtain:

```
> print(d2)

  ID Smoke Ever_Smoked
1  1    No           1
2  1    No           1
3  1   Yes           1
4  1    No           1
5  2    No           0
6  2    No           0
7  3   Yes           1
8  3    No           1
```